# Get current page programmatically

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2

In a JSF backing bean (Managed Bean, Weld Bean, doesn't matter), I can get the context path the client is on by calling

```
FacesContext ctx = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
String path = ctx.getExternalContext().getRequestContextPath();
```

This gives me the path the client currently accesses, like `/myapplication`.
Is it also possible to get the current *page*, like `/home.faces`, and how?

Answer (score 122, accepted):

You normally want to use [`UIViewRoot#getViewId()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/UIViewRoot.html#getViewId%28%29) for this.

```
String viewId = facesContext.getViewRoot().getViewId();
```

This is in EL also available as follows:

```
#{view.viewId}
```

Exactly this value is reuseable in navigation case outcomes such as `<h:link outcome>` and `<h:button outcome>`.

---

Alternatively, you can also use `HttpServletRequest#getRequestURI()` to get whatever the enduser is actually seeing in the browser address bar.

```
String uri = ((HttpServletRequest) externalContext.getRequest()).getRequestURI();
```

Which is in EL also available as follows:

```
#{request.requestURI}
```

Exactly this value is reuseable in `<h:outputLink value>` or plain `<a href>`. Note that you can't use it as navigation case outcome.

Comment: This does not reliably work. With PrettyFaces for example this does not give the URL that was called to create the current page.

Comment: @DoubleMalt: OP didn't indicate that he is using PrettyFaces.

Comment: While it is true he also did not explicitly state that he didn't. My point was simply that libraries that extend JSF might break your solution (and PrettyFaces is a pretty common enhancement as the standard implementation's handling of navigation is pretty clumsy).
I just wanted to give people that find out, that your clean solution doesn't work for them a clue why.

Comment: @DoubleMalt: I don't do PrettyFaces, but I'd be very surprised if its view handler doesn't determine the proper URL for a given navigation case outcome.

Comment: @DoubleMalt, Prettyfaces is supposed to be a mere url prettyfier. Your statement of `the standard implementation's handling of navigation is pretty clumsy`... Well, prettyfaces does nothing about navigation that JSF doesn't. It just maps its url's to a prettier ones. It also has parameter related functionalities, but I don't consider them to be navigation specific.

Comment: This sounds like a good idea, however casting getRequest to HttpServletRequest will throw the following error:

ClassCastException: com.liferay.portlet.RenderRequestImpl cannot be cast to javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest

Seems like getRequest() will return a PortletRequestImpl, and I am not sure how to get the URL using such class.

Comment: @Gaara: apparently you're developing a portlet app, not a servlet app. Sorry, portlets are beyond me. Just search around how to get request URI from a `PortletRequest` instance.

Answer (score 14):

Ok, got it, it's

```
FacesContext ctx = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
HttpServletRequest servletRequest = (HttpServletRequest) ctx.getExternalContext().getRequest();
// returns something like "/myapplication/home.faces"
String fullURI = servletRequest.getRequestURI();
```

Answer (score 3):

```
String uri = ((HttpServletRequest)FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequest()).getRequestURI();
```

Answer (score -2):

```
 String str = ((HttpServletRequest) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance() 
 .getExternalContext().getRequest()).getRequestURI(); 
 System.out.println(str);
```

Comment: Please explain your answer in words as well.

Comment: This does not add anything to the previous answer(s).