# Hide specific parts of a template depending on template client

Tags: templates, jsf, facelets

I have a header, body and footer defined in a Facelet template. I would like to hide the header and footer in my login page. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One of the ways would be to just render them conditionally based on the [current view ID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3253923/get-current-page-programmatically).

```
<h:panelGroup id="header" layout="block" rendered="#{view.viewId != '/login.xhtml'}">
    Header.
</h:panelGroup>

<div id="body">
    <ui:insert name="body">Body.</ui:insert>
</div>

<h:panelGroup id="footer" layout="block" rendered="#{view.viewId != '/login.xhtml'}">
    Footer.
</h:panelGroup>
```

Another way would be to parameterize it using `<ui:param>`:

```
<h:panelGroup id="header" layout="block" rendered="#{not hideHeaderAndFooter}">
    Header.
</h:panelGroup>

<div id="body">
    <ui:insert name="body">Body.</ui:insert>
</div>

<h:panelGroup id="footer" layout="block" rendered="#{not hideHeaderAndFooter}">
    Footer.
</h:panelGroup>
```

And then in the template client of `/login.xhtml`:

```
<ui:composition template="/WEB-INF/templates/layout.xhtml" ...>
    <ui:param name="hideHeaderAndFooter" value="true" />
    <ui:define name="body">
        ...
    </ui:define>
</ui:composition>
```