# JSF get current page

Tags: ajax, jsf, jsf-2, if-statement, primefaces

I would like to use an ajax tag based on which page is currently shown.
I am using JSF 2 and Primeface 3.5

> If (currentPage = pageOne.xhtml){  do something } else { do something
>   different }

My Source is looking like that:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
    xmlns:m="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite/components/mmnet"
    xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core">

    <h:form id="customerSearchForm">
....
...

<c:if test=" ">
<p:ajax event="rowSelect" oncomplete="initInfoPage();"/>
</c:if>

....
...
```

what is the correct expression inside ?

> test= ...

Is there a way to get which page is currently shown?

Regards
LStrike

Comment: I used #{view.viewId} to get current page. Look at this [EXAMPLE](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3255120/1692632)

Comment: #{view.viewId == 'pageOne.xhtm'}   please try  this i think its working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the ID of the current view via `#{view.viewID}`. This is basically the physical path of the template client file, relative to the webcontent root.

So, this should do, provided that `pageOne.xhtml` is directly in the root of the webcontent.

```
<c:if test="#{view.viewId == '/pageOne.xhtml'}">
```

Note that it starts with a leading slash and does not contain the JSF mapping, if any.