# How to get the URL of current page in JSF?

Tags: jsf, url, jsf-2

Is there any way to get the URL of the page which is loaded?

I would like the URL of the page which is loaded, in my controller i will call a method getUrlOfPage() in init() method .

I need the URL source to use it as a input for exporting the context in it.

How to get the URL of the page?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

It's available by [`HttpServletRequest#getRequestURL()`](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/platform/8/apidocs/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getRequestURL--) (with domain) or [`getRequestURI()`](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/platform/8/apidocs/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getRequestURI--) (without domain). The [`HttpServletRequest`](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/platform/8/apidocs/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html) itself is in turn available through JSF API via [`ExternalContext#getRequest()`](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/platform/8/apidocs/javax/faces/context/ExternalContext.html#getRequest--).

Thus, so:

```
public void someMethod() {
    HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequest();
    String url = request.getRequestURL().toString();
    String uri = request.getRequestURI();
    // ...
}
```

Or, if you're using CDI `@Named` to manage beans, and you're on JSF 2.3 or newer, then this is also possible through [`javax.faces.annotation.ManagedProperty`](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/platform/8/apidocs/javax/faces/annotation/ManagedProperty.html):

```
@Inject @ManagedProperty("#{request.requestURL}")
private StringBuffer url; // +setter

@Inject @ManagedProperty("#{request.requestURI}")
private String uri; // +setter

public void someMethod() {
    // ...
}
```

Or, if you're using CDI `@Named` to manage beans, then this is also possible, also on older JSF versions:

```
@Inject
private HttpServletRequest request;

public void someMethod() {
    String url = request.getRequestURL().toString();
    String uri = request.getRequestURI();
    // ...
}
```

Or, if you're still using the since JSF 2.3 deprecated `@ManagedBean`, then this is also possible through [`javax.faces.bean.ManagedProperty`](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/platform/8/apidocs/javax/faces/bean/ManagedProperty.html) (note that the bean can **only** be `@RequestScoped`!):

```
@ManagedProperty("#{request.requestURL}")
private StringBuffer url; // +setter

@ManagedProperty("#{request.requestURI}")
private String uri; // +setter

public void someMethod() {
    // ...
}
```

#### See also

- [Get current page programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3253923/get-current-page-programmatically)