# Navigate to previous page with JSF

Tags: jsf, omnifaces

I use a backing bean where I can save a form and navigate to this page.

```
public String saveHere() {
    return Faces.getViewId() + "?faces-redirect=true&includeViewParams=true";
}
```

How do I navigate to the previous page with OmniFaces?
My save action should result in the page where I have the "edit" button.
Typically a list-view (with edit-button next to very item)
or another page with (with edit-button to this item)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the page id you're navigating from somewhere. At first look, keeping it in Session seems to be a good idea, however, this could remain in coflict if you're navigating in multi-tab (sharing same Http Session through different browser tabs).

Having said that, the most proper solution for your case is to pass a view param to your edition view telling where you're coming from. That should be as easy as this:

```
<h:button outcome="edit" value="Edit registry">
    <f:param name="pageFrom" value="#{view.viewId}" />
</h:button>
```

After that, in your edition view bind this param to your bean:

```
<f:metadata>
    <f:viewParam name="pageFrom" value="#{editBean.pageFrom}" />
</f:metadata>
```

And just redirect to that view in your **EditBean.java** after saving, supposing it is `@ViewScoped`:

```
public String saveHere() {
    //save here
    return pageFrom + "?faces-redirect=true&includeViewParams=true";
}
```

That's the most straight forward way to achieve what you ask for. However, you must take into account the page where you're coming from remains to be a view parameter, so the end user could type what he wants there. With this behaviour, he could achieve being redirected to some other page rather than the one expected. If you want to avoid that, go with [the flash scope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11194112/understand-flash-scope-in-jsf2) instead of view parameters.

**See also:**

- [Get current page programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3253923/get-current-page-programmatically)