# Ignore postback calls when calling JavaScript window.history.back() on JSF 2

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsf-2, browser-history

I am using `window.history.back()` to navigate to a previous page inside my application.

However I have lot of cases like the following

`A-->B-->B(postback)`

in which i do post back inside the same page. For this case `window.history.back()` is not useful since it keeps going to the same page B until there are no postback navigations in history.

Is there some known and secure way of dealing with this situation?

Comment: Don't use that javascript method and implement a proper button to return to previous view, as explained [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24202285/navigate-to-previous-page-with-jsf)

Answer (score 0):

You should use `window.history.go()`. just use a hidden field to counter your post and finally navigate that number and use `.go()` function.