# dynamic view injection or routing

Tags: jsf, facelets, templating

i have a JSF projekt and in there i have different views, which are backed by ManagedBeans.

What i would like to achieve is to change some views while others stay where they are. this has to happen dynamically. In other words. I want to inject and remove views from an xhtml page without a page refresh. I have no clue how to achieve this.

Even better would be a dynamic view injection based on urls. angularjs does that very well.
But even without routing it would be great.

Thanks in advance.

Here is an example in pseudo code:

```
<nav>
    <h:link action="navigationBean.changeView(view1)" method="ajax">Link1</h:link>
    <h:link action="navigationBean.changeView(view2)" method="ajax">Link2</h:link>
</nav>

<h:viewContainer>
    // view selected by clicking the nav links should be injected here without page reload
</h:viewContainer>
```

Comment: What do you mean with "view injection"? Please, provide an example for explanation. Also remember that JSF is a server side framework which just generates HTML code. You could combine it with Angular with no problem.

Comment: changed my question to be more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you ask is better done using [Facelet templating](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/giqxp.html). You'll be able that way to have a page template with the shared content (the navigation menu in your case) and make the rest of the views inherit from it.

What can I see from your suggested solution is that you're abusing the *POST* calls. `#{fragmentsPresenter.changeView('viewOne')}` doesn't make sense just because you already know where you want to go to when you press that link (to `viewOne`), So you'll be better using plain links for that.

Here you've got an example showing how to handle navigation in a proper way. Let's suppose you've got a view controller even you won't need it in most of the cases:

**ViewController.java**

```
/**
 * Give the scope you want to your bean depending on what are your operations
 * oriented to. This example could be @ApplicationScoped as well
 * 
 * @author amaeztu
 * 
 */
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class ViewController {

    /**
     * Just gets the current view path and switches to the other one
     * 
     * @return
     */
    public String changeView() {
        String viewId = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot()
                .getViewId();
        if (viewId.equals("/view1.xhtml")) {
            return "/view2";
        } else {
            return "/view1";
        }
    }
}
```

This controller's job is just to check what view are you coming from and switch to the other one. It's pointless to perform a *POST* request (to send a form) just to navigate to the other view, while you could evaluate it before page rendering.

Here you've got how the template view is built:

**template.xhtml**

```xhtml
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html">
    <h:head />

    <h:body>
        <h:form>
            <!-- Use POST requests like this only when you have 
            to determine the destination dinamically at server side -->
            <h:commandButton value="Switch View with POST"
                action="#{viewController.changeView}" />
            <br />
        </h:form>
        <!-- For plain navigation, use GET requests -->
        <h:link value="Go to view 1" outcome="/view1" />
        <br />

        <!-- Determine where we are at page rendering time 
            and evaluate the other view path -->
        <h:link value="Switch view without POST"
            outcome="#{view.viewId eq '/view1.xhtml' ? '/view2' : '/view1'}" />
        <br />
        <br />
        <ui:insert name="content" />
    </h:body>

</ui:composition>
```

This template page defines a shared button/link set and calls for content. I've implemented different kind of navigation options. Using [`<h:link />`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/j2ee/javaee/javaserverfaces/2.0/docs/pdldocs/facelets/h/link.html) is, in this case, the most straight-forward way. Check the second link, here we evaluate the current view id when it gets rendered and a link to go to the opposite one is created. Cool, isn't it?

Now here it is the implementation of the child views:

**view1.xhtml**

```xhtml
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html" template="/template.xhtml">

    <ui:define name="content">
        <!-- Here you could have some @ViewScoped 
        bean managing the content i.e. #{view1Bean} -->
        View 1
    </ui:define>

</ui:composition>
```

**view2.xhtml**

```xhtml
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html" template="/template.xhtml">

    <ui:define name="content">
        View 2
    </ui:define>

</ui:composition>
```

You'll be able to type their address in your browser and see them, that's what's called bookmarkable ;-)

**See also:**

- [Get current page programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3253923/get-current-page-programmatically)

Comment: Is it possible to only render <ui:insert> with ajax? as it is it will refresh the whole page which i try to avoid.

Comment: It is possible to design something similar as your posted solution, with an static page and central content rendered using Ajax. However, keep in mind that as I told before, GET requests are recommended for page to page navigation. Ajax postbacks are a handy tool to refresh some current view content or send partial form data. My tip is to avoid Ajax for any different usage. Other choice could be to use `ui:include` with no Ajax, but I think templates are the best solution for your case by far. Give them a try.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i solved it as follows:

my View:

```xhtml
<h:body>

<nav>
<h:form>
    <h:commandLink action="#{fragmentsPresenter.changeView('viewOne')}">
        viewOne
        <f:ajax execute="@this" render="fragment-container" />
    </h:commandLink>
    <h:commandLink action="#{fragmentsPresenter.changeView('viewTwo')}">
        viewTwo
        <f:ajax execute="@this" render="fragment-container" />
    </h:commandLink>
</h:form>
</nav>

<h:panelGroup id="fragment-container">
    <ui:fragment rendered="#{fragmentsPresenter.activeView('viewOne')}">
        <div>i am view one!</div>
    </ui:fragment>
    <ui:fragment rendered="#{fragmentsPresenter.activeView('viewTwo')}">
        <div>i am view Two!</div>
        <ui:include src="fragment.xhtml"/>
    </ui:fragment>
</h:panelGroup>
```

and my ManagedBean:

```
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class FragmentsPresenter {
    private String activeView;

    public void setActiveView(String viewName) { this.activeView = viewName; }
    public String getActiveView() { return this.activeView; }

    public FragmentsPresenter() { this.activeView = "viewOne"; }

    public void changeView(String viewName) { this.activeView = viewName; }

    public boolean activeView(String viewName) {
        return activeView.equals(viewName);
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, it seems a proper solution. However, just a question, are that commandLinks a kind of menu for your whole application navigation? If yes, then you should go with templating, I consider it to be much more useful than rendering the same view once and again as you're doing. Mainly because it provides you with bookmarkable urls.

Comment: I would be able to provide you a kickoff example if you want.

Comment: sure, i would really appreciate that.