# JSF - Pass argument to @PostConstruct method

Tags: jsf, facelets, jsf-2.2, managed-bean, postconstruct

I am using JSF 2.2 and I have two facelets pages that use the same managed bean. And I want to perform different actions on @PostConstruct method depending on the page.

Is there a way to do the following:

```
    @PostConstruct
    public void init()
    {
        if(argument.equals("page1")
        {
            ...
        }
        else if(argument.equals("page2")
        {
            ...
        }
    }
```

Comment: You could try with viewId `facesContext.getViewRoot().getViewId()` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3253923/get-current-page-programmatically

Comment: Thanks for your answer! It works!